# jQuery add class to current li and remove prev li when click inside li a

Tags: jquery, html

here is html:

```
<ul>    
    <li class="current"><a href="#">menu item</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#aba">menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#abb">menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#abc">menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#abd">menu item</a></li>
</ul>
```

if I press 'a' link it will addClass 'current' to clicked li and remove old li class?
this is my try:

```
$('ul li a').click(function(){
  $('ul li').removeClass('current');
  ... don't know here (add class to current li) ...
});
```

Comment: jQuery has great documentation which is worth a read: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use [`.parent('li')`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) or [`.closest('li')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to select the clicked `<li>`.

```
$('ul li a').click(function() {
    $('ul li.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('current');
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Use on('click') if you are using latest version of jquery

```
$('ul li a').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
});
```

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GG7ZZ/).

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ul li a').click(function(){
  $('ul').children().removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

Hope, this will works for you..

Comment: In @Rob's words: `this` is the `<a>` element.

Answer (score 2):

Rob is right but 
`$('ul li.current').removeClass('current');` didn't work for me.
Following code works.

```
jQuery('ul li a').click(function() 
{

jQuery('ul').children().removeClass('selected');
jQuery(this).closest('li').addClass('selected');
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){

   $('ul li a').click(function(){
      var item=$(this).parent();
       $('ul li').removeClass('current');
       item.addClass("current")
    });

});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z8DYP/3/

Answer (score 0):

Just add the the class to `this` like so...

```
$(this).addClass('yourClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this?

```
$('ul li').each(function(){
  var t = $(this);
  t.find('a').click(function() {
    $('ul li').removeClass('current');
    t.addClass('current');
  });
});
```