# jQuery add class to current li and remove prev li

Tags: jquery

I found this [jQuery add class to current li and remove prev li when click inside li a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688778/jquery-add-class-to-current-li-and-remove-prev-li-when-click-inside-li-a), but it doesn't work for me.

`header.jsp`

```
<ul>    
  <li class="current"><a href="#">menu item</a></li>  
  <li><a href="aba.jsp">menu item</a></li>
  <li><a href="abb.jsp">menu item</a></li>
  <li><a href="abc.jsp">menu item</a></li>
  <li><a href="abd.jsp">menu item</a></li>
</ul>

$('ul li a').click(function(){
  $('ul li.current').removeClass('current');
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('current');
});
```

Other jsp pages include this header.jsp. After I added the jQuery as the link said, the class is added temporarily, and then it is like refreshed and the page goes back to its initial state which is the first `li` has the class `current`. Any idea?

UPDATE: `href="#aba"` to `href="aba.jsp"`

Comment: How can we tell what you did wrong if you don't show your code?

Comment: Can you reproduce this on jsFiddle.net?

Comment: Are the links taking you to a new page?

Comment: @Barmar code is updated, it is the same with the code in the link.

Comment: I guess you didn't put your event in document.ready

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan No, it doesn't work either

Comment: @Cacheing Changes made to the DOM with javascript don't persist automatically from one page to the next or between refreshes. When you go to the new page, the changes you made to the DOM on the last page are lost.

Comment: You're missing `.current` in the `removeClass` line.

Comment: @JasonP Then any way to keep the change? Or how should I implement the feature?

Comment: Either send the changes to the server using `AJAX` so it will construct the new page correctly, or save the state in a cookie or localStorage and update the page when it's reloaded.

Comment: @Barmar I added it, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You could also, when the page loads, check the menu link urls against the current page url, and highlight the correct one. That could be done client or server side.

Comment: @JasonP is correct about DOM changes not persisting, but if your links are all actually to internal links, there shouldn't be a reload.  If you are accessing new pages (i.e. links without a leading #), then you'll lose the changes to the DOM.  If that's the case, you'll want to track what was clicked and highlight accordingly . . .

Comment: Try adding `return false;` to the end of the function.

Comment: @JasonP I like the way that you suggested to compare the menu link url against page url, I will try to implement that.

Comment: @Barmar Umm, doesn't work

Comment: @ernie the link is a new page like `home.jsp`, yea, I should update my code.

Answer (score 0):

The code, as it is, works: http://jsfiddle.net/GGCNd/. But it not suit for your case.

Any link your access, post you do or reloading page. Anything that do http request, you erase your changes via JavaScript.

You have to load a JS function every time you load the pages with this menu, or do a Post in a page that require reloading.

The function must compare current page and the list of links in the menu, adding `class="current"` to the match.